# Angular - Uncaught Error: Cannot match any routes 'home'

Tags: angular, typescript

I know that this question has been asked on this website multiple times, but answers still do not agree with one another, and none of the answers solve my problem - I think that I may pose my question here.

The error report:

```
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home'
```

`routes.ts`:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { MenuComponent } from '../menu/menu.component';
import { DishdetailComponent } from '../dishdetail/dishdetail.component';
import { HomeComponent } from '../home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from '../about/about.component';
import { ContactComponent } from '../contact/contact.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'menu',  component: MenuComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

`app-routing.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './routes';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing : true })
  ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ],
  declarations: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Excerpt from `header.component.html`:

```
<a mat-button routerLink="/home"><span class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></span> Home</a>

<a mat-button routerLink="/menu"><span class="fa fa-list fa-lg"></span> Menu</a>
```

This is the sample code I copy from an online exercise (Coursera), and these code work perfectly fine on the lecturer's computer. I cannot figure out why. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Ithink you have to  replace `redirectTo: '/home'` by `redirectTo: 'home'`

Comment: @veben it doesn't work...

Comment: I have updated my answer with working demo for you. Let try this and let u know.

Answer (score 0):

try to edit routes.ts:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { MenuComponent } from '../menu/menu.component';
import { DishdetailComponent } from '../dishdetail/dishdetail.component';
import { HomeComponent } from '../home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from '../about/about.component';
import { ContactComponent } from '../contact/contact.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'menu',  component: MenuComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missing simple changes.Change like this,

```
 { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }

 to
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

Also make sure your index.html file pointing like this **bass href** properties

```
<base href="/">
```

let try this once and let you know..

**Update:**

I have created Slackblitz working example for you. Let try this once best way for routing.

routing:-

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { HomeComponent  } from './home/home.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './error/error.component';
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: ErrorComponent
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { HomeComponent  } from './home/home.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './error/error.component';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, AppRoutingModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, HomeComponent,LoginComponent, ErrorComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ce7ti3

Output:-

[image]

I hope its solve your problem and help to you..

Thanks,
Muthukumar

Comment: I have updated my answer with working example. Let try this once.

Comment: Yep, this works perfectly fine but I am still confused that why my example doesn't work properly...

Comment: did you check all are applied properly your code. Especially
 /home to home

Comment: Yes it still doesn't work when I apply these changes

Comment: Yes, but that's too much work. Do you have a google account? I may upload the folder to my google cloud and you may download the project.

Comment: The document is too large... this method doesn't work